# Grouping together values to display in Label using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a situation and need some help to solve this. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmFXa.jpg)

I am not allowed to embed images directly to the post. As you can see the image, Data is displayed in the gridview, but client wants it to displayed as text one below another like text below the gridivew. However, there is a requirement to display Filenames together which have common date. E.g : 04/18/2015, there are two different file entries and want PAYROLL_*******20150429.csv to be displayed under PAYROLL******_20150422.csv. So no need for third entry, just want 2nd and 3rd to be clubbed together. There could be different files with same date entry, and they need to be clubbed together. The first Name, 191_20150418 is based on the date entry.

I am using Win forms with C#. I have gathered the data in the data table to display in the gridview. 
This is my code below to display in the Label:

```
Label.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Name : " + dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Name"] + Environment.NewLine +
                                            "PPED : " + dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Date"] + Environment.NewLine +
                                            "Files : " + dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Files"] + Environment.NewLine;
```

Please suggest a better way if adding like this in label is not feasible.

Comment: If it works, what constitutes "a better way"?

Comment: You could use `string.Format()` or string interpolation (i.e `$""`).  If these values are coming out of a class you have created you can add this logic in an override `ToString()` method

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't anything *wrong* with doing this:

```
Label.Text += 
    Environment.NewLine + "Name : " + dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Name"] +
    Environment.NewLine + "PPED : " + dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Date"] +
    Environment.NewLine + "Files : " + dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Files"] +
    Environment.NewLine;
```

However you could use string.Format():

```
Label.Text += string.Format("{0}Name : {1}{0}PPED : {2}{0}Files : {3}{0}",
    Environment.NewLine, 
    dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Name"], 
    dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Date"], 
    dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Files"]);
```

Or [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings)  if you are using C# 6/.NET 4.6:

```
Label.Text += $"{Environment.NewLine}Name : {dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Name"]}{Environment.NewLine}PPED : {dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Date"]}{Environment.NewLine}Files : {dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Files"]}{Environment.NewLine}";
```

It looks like you are using a DataTable for accessing this data, but in the future if you are using a custom defined class you could override the `ToString()` method of your class using any one of the above methods:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}Name : {1}{0}PPED : {2}{0}Files : {3}{0}",
        Environment.NewLine, 
        dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Name"], 
        dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Date"], 
        dtSWAction.Rows[i]["Files"]);
}
```

Then anytime in the future you could just call it like this:

```
Label.Text += instanceOfYourClass.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you look at the image attached it’s the link in my question. I am trying to display two different file names with same date together and not have two entries like the way I am doing right now.